# How to get Start and End of Road lat long in Google Map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Just wondering if it is possible to get a start and End point of Road in Google Map ApI? For example if I have a Lat long as: I have Position as 20.220966,100.627899 and I would like to get lat long A(Start of road) B (End of road) within 20 Km buffer?

Comment: not clear enough. What you want to do is to go 10km up and 10 down the road from your position (latLng) and get the latlng of each extremity?

Comment: Or your initial latlng is, sayn in road "MyRoad" and you want to know where this "MyRoad" begins and where this "MyRoad" ends?, so the extemities of "MyRoad"

Comment: Hi Sabotero, thanks for your comments and sorry for confusion! What I want is just listing all roads in an area with radios of 20 km. Lets say we have an Hospital at X position with lat long 20.220966, 100.627899 Ok, what I want to know if there is a way to list all street around the hospital with radios 20? like what we do on Place searching!